# Calling active wp_posts row

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Is it possible to echo a value from the active post in wordpress?

Example: If I make a row called: post_numberofreads and I want to echo this value for each post, by inserting a line of code in the single post template page (single.php) that calls any given posts 'post_numberofreads'. How would I go about doing this?

Please notice that this is an example. The important part is that I want to echo something from the active row - not just get the number of reads.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the ideal solution is to create a wordpress plugin with your custom functionalities but it require good understanding of wordpress and plugin development.

The other solution more can be to inject your custom code in the wordpress core manually. I is comparatbiliy easy and often unsecure and get broke frequently.

For second option you can:

A) Create required custom columns in `wp-posts` in wordpress database using phpmyadmin or your favourite tool.

B) Inject your code into the relevant files. Generally these files are:

```
wp-content/themes/your_theme/single.php #For blog post
wp-content/themes/your_theme/page.php   #For pages
```

C) Then you can using built in wordpress functions like [`get_the_ID`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) to get current post ID. You can also other wordpress functions to communicate with wordpress database or write your own functions.